# Bandwidth throughput with an HTTP server

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to set up nginx as a reverse proxy for static files (images and videos).

Can anybody share some throughput statistics he got with nginx (and other servers in general)? Do you think a high-end server can handle hundreds or even thousands Mbit/s? (I know streaming servers can, don't know about HTTP servers.)

Comment: If you have the bandwidth.

Comment: The servers are planned to be connected on a 10GE connection, and most clients are at a distance of maximum 186 miles (300 kilometers).

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Median request size, number of keep-alive connections, filesystem cache hit ratio, NIC driver quality, and dirver/OS tuning parameters all matter a great deal. With the filesystem cache being the most important.

For example, it will be easy to hit 10 Gbps if your sending out copies of the same 500 Mbyte video to a few hundred clients simultaneously and the whole video file is in cache. If you are serving billions of small images or javascripts, and the cache hit ratio is low, you will be lucky to serve 100 Mbps.

As good as nginx is, how fast it can send is limited by how fast it can read data. 10 Gbps is roughly 1 GByte/sec. If the data set is *all* coming from RAM cache, that's do-able. Otherwise, you're going to bottleneck at the storage layer (unless you have a several fast SSDs in a RAID configuration or a whole lot of spinning rust). Also note that you will need to run several nginx worker processes per core in order to avoid blocking on disk access under Linux because asynchronous IO in Linux is basically broken by design.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the throughput is limited by the number of requests per second. This is dependent of a lot of factors.

The first bottleneck will be the storage. You can remove this bottleneck by using a lot of memory for file system cache.

The next bottleneck will be CPU load caused by interrupts. You will solve this by using NICs that allow offloading of various tasks and configuring interrupt coalescing.

Next will be the nginex CPU usage. You will solve this by scaling up (use better CPUs), then horizontally (add more CPUs and servers).

For all changes do load testing and monitor everything (CPU, I/O, switches load, etc). Make sure that you will use some good hardware as test machines, otherwise the bottleneck might become your test machine.